# not able to import contacts from sdcard in cyanogenmod 10.1.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have just installed cyanogenmod 10.1.2

My problem is that whenever I try to import contacts from external card (using the build in import/export functionality of contacts),

I get an error saying

```
"The SD card couldn't be scanned. 
 (Reason: I/O error)"
```

I am not able to move applications on external sdcard also. All of them installing to internal storage only.

How do I fix these.

Also under the file explorer i am able to access my external sdcard in `storage/sdcard1` folder, which is having permissions like this `d---rwxr-x`.

Does has something to do with the above. How do I make sure that all the applications are installed on sdcard only (if supported).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you already named the culprit: Your card is mounted at `/mnt/sdcard1`, and the apps probably look at `/mnt/sdcard0` for the card in your microSD slot, assuming that "higher numbers" are simply attached via OTG. At least that's my first thought -- but I haven't verified that, so take it rather as a "pointer to check" (which is why I don't make it an answer until approved).

Comment: seems like it's jelly bean 4.2. that doesn't allow using external sdcard for storing apps data..

"FolderMount" (application on play store) seems to do the trick but it has it's limits in free version..